# a cut containing exactly one edge in each path

Tags: graphs, minimum-cuts

Given a digraph with a source $s$ and target $t$, must there be an edge cut which contains exactly one edge in every path from $s$ to $t$?  I'm not interested in a minimum cut; any cut would do.

If not, how close to "exactly one" can we get?

Comment: Do you mean any path or edge-disjoint or vertex-disjoint path? A minimum edge-cut contains exactly one edge from each edge-disjoint path between $s$ and $t$.

Comment: Let me give an example; I'm not sure that we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: Consider the graph with nodes 1,2,3,4, and edges 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4, 1->3, and 2-> 4.    Take the source to be 1 and the target to be 4.  Then C = {1->2, 3->4} is a cut: on removing them, there's no path from 1 to 4.   But  not every path in the original graph from 1 to 4  has exactly one edge in C: the path 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 would be a counterexample since it has two edges in C.  On the other hand, {2->4, 3->4} would be a cut with the property that I'm after: every path from 1 to 4 has exactly one edge in it.

Comment: This is impossible, the number of paths can be exponential in terms of $n$, while the number of edges is at most $n^2$.

Comment: @orezvani Every cut contains *at least* one edge of every $s$ to $t$ path.

Comment: Is your graph a DAG? What do you mean by a "path from $s$ to $t$"? Does it have to be simple? I am asking since if the graph is a DAG, then you can take all edges outgoing from $s$ or all edges incoming to $t$, and whether this construction works in general could depend on your definition of *path*.

Comment: I'm indeed mainly interested in this question on DAGs, and I have in mind paths which are simple.  So your point is right.   But I really have in mind further questions which aren't so immediate.  For example, is every edge contained in a cut of the kind I'm after?  Which sets of edges can be extended to such cuts?

Comment: I updated the algorithm, but you might end up getting the same results as the one that Yuval mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what do you exactly mean by "path".

**Edge-disjoint paths --** Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, a minimum edge-cut consists of one edge for every edge-disjoint path between $s$ and $t$.

**Vertex-disjoint paths --** Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, a minimum vertex-cut consists of one vertex for every vertex-disjoint path between $s$ and $t$. Therefore, the set of edges incident to the vertices in the cut (out-edges) consist of one edge per vertex-disjoint path between $s$ and $t$.

Having exactly one edge per every simple path between $s$ and $t$ is impossible. The reason is that the number of edges in the cut must be equal to the number of simple paths between $s$ and $t$, however, the number of simple paths between two vertices $s$ and $t$ can be exponential in terms of $n$, while the number of edges is at most $n^2$. Using Pigeonhole principle, it can be shown that it is impossible to find such solution.

The following example shows that the number of paths between $s$ and $t$ is $2^{(n-2)/2}$, while the number of edges between them is $2n-4$.

[image]

If you are interested in finding a set of edges that consists of at least one edge from every path between $s$ and $t$, then you can use the minimum edge-cut between $s$ and $t$.
If you are considering a case where you need at least one edge from each path, and no more than one edges per path, you can use an approach that is similar to minimum cut algorithm, but I am not sure how efficient it would be in practice.

1. Find the minimum edge-cut between $s$ and $t$;
2. Using a graph traversal algorithm (i.e. DFS), find if there is a path that goes over two of the edges in the cut;
3. If you find a such a path, remove those edges $(u_1, v_1), \cdots, (u_k, v_k)$ from the cut $C$ and replace them with the minimum cut from each $u_i$ to $t$ ($1 \leq i \leq k$), and repeat from 2;
4. If there is no such path then output $C$ and terminate;

Comment: Thanks.   I am interested in sets of edges with exactly one edge from every path, but I don't insist that different paths have different edges in my set.   In your picture, the set of two edges into t would do it.   Every path from s to t has exactly one edge in that set.    My example shows that not every minimum edge-cut works.   Does your last comment answer my question?

Comment: @LarryMoss Then minimum edge-cut should do the job, as in my second last paragraph.

Comment: Sorry to say, minimum edge-cut doesn't always work: there's an easy example with 4 vertices.  So I have yet to see a proof that there always is a set of edges between s and t with the property I want.

Comment: @LarryMoss The example that you made is not correct. Considering the same example, the minimum cut consists of only one edge ${(1,2)}$.

Comment: @LarryMoss But in general, minimum cut cannot guarantee that there will be at most one edge per simple path between $s$ and $t$. I initially thought that way, but it is not correct.